# Understanding linux shell script expression

Tags: linux, shell

Hi I have a small script (script name is: test1.sh) that looks like this

```
PRG=$0
data=`expr $PRG : '.*\/.*'`
echo $data
```

When I run this I see output as

> 10

I could not understand the regular expression written in the second line of the script.
What would that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression returns a non-zero value if there is a `/` within the relative filename of the script (`$0 in sh`). If you execute the script like this: `sh ../../script.sh`, it outputs 15, which is the total length of "../../script.sh". It matches "../../" with `'.*\/` and matches `script.sh` with the `.*` part.

Answer (score 2):

[From](http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html)

```
If the match succeeds the `:'
     expression returns the number of characters
     matched.
```

So the 10 is likely

```
./test1.sh
^^^^^^^^^^
||||||||| \
123456789 10
```

Comment: Since the question asked about the meaning of the regular expression, it will match 0 or more of any character, followed by a slash, followed by 0 or more of any character. The expr command matches specifically from the beginning of the input string. So this explains why it would match the entire string, if $0 == "./test1.sh". Also note that $0 in a bash script refers to the script name, as this answer implies.